Firebase Firestore Listener Not Unsubscribing
I have a Firebase Firestore listener function in my .api file below;
export function getRedemptionsListener(user_id, venue_id, callback) {
  const redemptions = [];
  firestore()
    .collection(`users/${user_id}/redemptions`)
    .where("venue.venue_id", "==", venue_id)
    .where("used", "==", true)
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        redemptions.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
      });
      callback(redemptions);
    });
}

I am calling it in my screen here;
  function getData() {
    Promise.all([getProfile(user.uid), getVenue(id), getOffers(id)])
      .then(([profile, venue, offers]) => {
        const isFavourite = profile?.favourites?.includes(id);
        setIsFavourite(isFavourite);
        setVenue(venue);
        const updatedOffers = matchOffers(offers, []);
        setOffers(updatedOffers);
        const subscriber = getRedemptionsListener(user.uid, id, (redemptions) => {
          setRedemptions(redemptions);
          const updatedOffersWithRedemptions = matchOffers(offers, redemptions);
          setOffers(updatedOffersWithRedemptions);
        });
        subscriber();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }

When I log out of my app function below;
return (
  <NavigationContainer theme={colorScheme === "light" ? DefaultTheme : DarkTheme}>
    {user ? <SignedInLayout /> : <AuthLayout />}
  </NavigationContainer>
);

I get the error;

Cannot read property forEach of null
from querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

I'm assuming this is because the listener is not being removed.
I have tried the below in my .api file but the listener doesn't work in this case.
export function getRedemptionsListener(user_id, venue_id, callback) {
  const redemptions = [];
  const subscriber = firestore()
    .collection(`users/${user_id}/redemptions`)
    .where("venue.venue_id", "==", venue_id)
    .where("used", "==", true)
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        redemptions.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
      });
      callback(redemptions);
    });
    return subscriber();
}


Your first code sample not only doesn't remove the listener (which could be a costly mistake), but it also accumulates results into redemptions, growing it indefinitely over time as the documents change.  Both of these things are pretty bad.  If you need to get data just once, then you shouldn't use a listener at all.  Just get() the query and deal with the returned promise.

querySnapshot should never be null, though, so you might want to debug further to find out if the error is actually with the code you show here.
